# Displaying my JSON in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

These are my Json arrays:

```
{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"2015-01-11 12:30:45","DateTimeCreated":"2015-01-11 12:30:45","2":"Pending Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending Confirmation","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}

{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"2015-02-11 09:09:09","DateTimeCreated":"2015-02-11 09:09:09","2":"Pending Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending Confirmation","3":"LSH","username":"LSH"}

{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"2015-12-03 18:30:00","DateTimeCreated":"2015-12-03 18:30:00","2":"Unresolved","status_desc":"Unresolved","3":"SWJH","username":"SWJH"}

{"0":"12","id":"12","1":"2014-12-03 12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03 12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}

{"0":"14","id":"14","1":"2014-12-03 12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03 12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"CYJM","username":"CYJM"}
```

How am I supposed to use these to display my code in an HTML file?

I have a function to show the data but it does not work:

```
function showData(response) {

        var data = JSON.parse(response);

        var id = data.id;
        var DateTimeCreated = data.DateTimeCreated;
        var status_desc = data.status_desc;
        var username = data.username;


        myText.textContent= id + DateTimeCreated + status_desc + username;
}
```

Comment: data is an array, but what you are showing yet you access it as if it were a single object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a **div** tag in your html template.

For example, in your HTML template, there should be a scope of codes:

```
<div id="sometext">
</div>
```

And in your JS script,

```
var textContent = id + DateTimeCreated + status_desc + username
sometext = document.getElementById("sometext");
sometext.innerHTML(textContent);
```

For more info, please visit http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I'm not entirely sure when you are using the showData function. However, here's a jsfiddle that shows that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/qyy2nvtz/1/

```
<p id='hello'></p>
var myText = document.getElementById('hello');
```

You need to get an element before you can display something in it. So, I've initialized 'myText' with a paragraph element with id 'hello'.

Additionally, make sure that the response that is being passed in to showData is a string before you parse it. If it's already an object, then it won't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example, you need a div element to refer like "js":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="js">
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myText= document.getElementById("js");
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    var id = data.id;
    var DateTimeCreated = data.DateTimeCreated;
    var status_desc = data.status_desc;
    var username = data.username;
    myText.textContent = id + DateTimeCreated + status_desc +username;
</script>
</html>
```

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp